# GWT-RPC call passing a UiBinder Element

Tags: gwt, element, gwt-rpc, uibinder

Good morning everbody,

I'm trying to pass a UiBinder from a rpc-service to the client page.
The problem is, that he throws an error, because the "Deferred binding failed". Can somebody explain, why this happens and if there is a workaround for dynamicly loading new UiBinder Elements to a webpage?

Regards, Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to pass an UiBinder xml to the client it's not going to work, because the UiBinder xml is not intended for runtime use, but only used at compile time. So in your running client there is no UiBinder xml anymore nor any functionality to use it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

UIBinder is a client-side concept and isn't something that you want to serialize and transmit between client and server. With GWT, you'll want to get away from the mindset of the UI being built on the server and pushed down to the client. The server should provide data to the client and the client uses that data to generate or modify the UI.

As to the nuts-and-bolts of why it failed for you, "deferred binding failed" usually means that the compiler was looking for a class that isn't part of a GWT module. The full message probably included the parenthetical question, "(did you forget to inherit a required module?)"